# Read file into dictionary and manipulate data

Tags: python

I am trying to read a text file and delete certain lines from it, if some values exceed an amount that i choose.

It's a text file that holds a map and I need to manipulate the values in the 3rd column. And then write the new map into a different file (or edit the same file). Note that those values are 3-4 characters long.

This is how the map looks like (relevant values in bold type)

> 1 979 **999** 514 383 117 95 1
>
> 1 979 **1000** 514 383 117 95 1

I managed to write a clean short code for reading from files. This is what i have so far:

```
List = []
for line in open('textFile.txt','r').readlines():
    List.append(line.strip())
    print(line)
```

Now i need a way to identify the relevant values on each line and set a condition that will hold the manipulation (deleting values in this case).

I've tried to compare a certain range in a specific line as an array to an integer but that did not work.

I also tried placing it all in one string and setting an exponential loop that will delete every characters that reside in the [6] to [10] range (growing exponentially) but that turned out to be too complicated for me.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Don't use `.readlines()` there; the file object is already an iterator over its lines.

Comment: Will the value you want to check ALWAYS be the 3rd from the left?

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing where dictionaries come in to this ...

Comment: Do you want to delete the full line based on the 3rd column, or just the number in the 3rd column?

Comment: Yes it will always be the 3rd from the left. I think i did not explain it well enough... It can range from 1-4 characters long.

Comment: Yes i want to delete the full line based on the 3rd column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read the data into a list of lists:

```
with open('testFile.txt') as fin:
    data = [line.split() for line in fin]
```

Now you can manipulate the data in the third column:

```
for line in data:
    print line[2] #prints the values in the third column
```

And to write it back out -- Here I'll write it to a different file, but it could be written back to the input file:

```
with open('testFile_out.txt','w') as fout:
    for line in data:
        fout.write(' '.join(line)+'\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

An example of updating the file in-place excluding records where the 3rd column is greater than 1000:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('yourfile', inplace=True):
    cols = line.split()
    if int(cols[2]) > 1000:
        continue
    print line,
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you could simply [split the string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html), manipulate the value and then put it all back together. So for example

```
List = []
for line in open('textFile.txt','r').readlines():
    tl = line.split(' ')
    tl[2] += 1
    List.append(' '.join(tl))
```

No need to iterate multiple times over one set of data really and if you need more clear code, just break it down into functions.

Comment: No problem and welcome to SO. Keep in mind that you should avoid just simple "thanks" comments, instead just vote an answer up ;).

Comment: Oh, sorry but i can't vote up yet as i don't have enough reputation.